# Swift UITapGestureRecognizer not working as intended

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a simple `UITapGestureRecognizer` and a print statement inserted in its corresponding method. The following is the code I have written:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.segmentTapped(sender:)))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.segmentedControl.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

That code above is executed in the `viewDidLoad` method.

In addition, its target method is:

```
func segmentTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("called")
}
```

The problem that exists with the program is that the word "called" is only printed in the console when the `segmentedControl` is tapped **twice**. It is not printed out if it is simply tapped once. I am confused as to why this is happening, because I have set the `numberOfTapsRequired` property of the gesture to 1.

Comment: What type is `segmentedControl`? The fact that it has "control" in the name makes me think something else may be capturing the gesture

Comment: This is because that the segmented control has its own gesture that handles your tap for its section button.

Comment: Doug, I am using a third party library called KMSegmentedControl. The link to the library: https://cocoapods.org/pods/KMSegmentedControl

Comment: If you want to use that segmented control then just add target actions to handle the tap.

Comment: in that link you gave there is a delegate 'func KMSegmentedControl(selected item: UIButton)' where you can handle those taps

Comment: +nferocious76 I tried using the delegate method, but for some odd reason it wouldn't work. As a result, I resorted to UITapGestureRecognizer. However, I deleted the app and reinstalled it with the delegate method, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **segmentedControl** to perform the desired action. Instead of adding GestureRecognizer for segmentedControl you can use action for the segmentedControl. Just like :

```
@IBAction func segmentControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
   print("called")
   } else {
    // do something else
 }
}
```

OR

you can even use

```
self.yourSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action:#selector(segmentTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

func segmentTapped(sender: UISegmentedControl)
{ 
   print("called")
// Do what you want
}
```